# How to change hero image based on html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a website I'm trying to build. The main page has a hero image, and on the second page I want to display a different hero image.

For `index.html`:

```
<!--Hero Section-->
<header id="about">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1 id="homeHeading">Hone is home</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>this text is ontop of the hero image</p>
            <a href="#deal" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
    min-height: auto;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    color: #fff;
}
```

For `membership.html` (the page where I'd like the hero image to change):

```
<!--Hero Section-->
<header id="member">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1 id="homeHeading">Hone is home</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>This text is on top of the hero image</p>
            <a href="#deal" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- / Hero section-->
```

I tried to override the hero image using the `id='member'`:

```css
header #member {
    background-image: url(../img/header2.jpg) !important;
}
```

But that doesn't work. So I thought maybe I could try some JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    #member {
        background-image: url('./img/header2.jpg');
    }
}
```

and

```
$(function() {
     $("header").attr("src", "../img/header2.jpg")
})
```

But neither worked. Please note that this isn't a website that's going live, it's for practice and for me to try and figure things out if I can.

Comment: Just for kicks, try putting in the full URL of the images on that last attempt.

Comment: @Difster I tried it, unfortunately no luck haha, that would have been entertaining if it worked though

Comment: I was just trying to see if maybe you just had the image path wrong. ;)

Comment: header#member   no space in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two classes, one common to both header tags and another specific to the `id` of the header. Also there is no need for `!important` as `id` has higher specificity.

Note that there is no space between tag and id in CSS, that is, it should be `header#id`.

HTML:

```
<!--Hero Section-->
<header id="about" class="commonHeader">
    // rest of code
</header>

<!--Hero Section-->
<header id="member" class="commonHeader">
    // rest of the code
</header>
```

CSS:

```css
.commonHeader {
    min-height: auto;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: #fff;
}

header#member {
    background-image: url(../img/header2.jpg);
}

header#about{
    background-image: url(someOtherImage);
}
```

Comment: ohhh man I didn't even think of separating it into two classes like that. awesome solution, and thanks for the headsup on the spacing issue with tag and ID in css!

Comment: Clarification: There is no space between the element name and id, when you want to target an element with a specific id. A selector *with* a space, such as `header #member`, would match an element with `id=member` which is a *descendant* of `<header>` (eg. `<header><div><p id=member>`).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong CSS selector. You should use something like this:

```css
header#member {
     background-image: url(../img/header2.jpg);
}
```

There shouldn't be space between `header` and `#member`. Your current selector means the `#member` tag that is a descendant of a `header` tag. And there is no need for `!important`.

Comment: thank you for the input! that explains why my css wasn't working for previous things

Comment: Terminology quibble: CSS selectors target *elements*, not tags. Tags only exist in the source text before it is rendered into a DOM object. Some elements don't even need tags at all, but can still be targeted by CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code**

```
 header #member {
  background-image: url(../img/header2.jpg) !important;
 }
```

you need to use

```
header#member{
  background-image: url(../img/header2.jpg);
}
```

JS

**Your Code**

```
window.onload = function(){
    #member {
        background-image: url('./img/header2.jpg');
    }
}
```

This don't Work

***Using jQuery***

**Your Code**

```
$(function() {
     $("header").attr("src", "../img/header2.jpg");
});
```

you need to use

```
$("header#member").css("background-image","path to image");
```